# Not able to build or run my android application

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, sdk

I am not able to run my android application in Android Studio. The project is properly working in my old device with `Android Studio Dolphin`, and I have to move it to new device with `Android Studio Flamingo`. I tried many of the solutions from Stack Overflow but all in vain. Also I tried

- Invalidating cache and restarting
- installed all possible SDK versions
- Deleted .gradle,.idea files and run again

but still issue persists. Any kind of help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Use the AGP Upgrade Assistant from the Tools it will upgrade the gradle.

Comment: @VishnuSDharan Tried already, but doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

The output issues log has already told you that it's your jdk version is not support. I think your environment via your computer install jdk version(17) is to much higher. You should try jdk1.7 or jdk1.8.

Also you can check your project build.gradle file

```
android{
    ......
    compileOptions{
         sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
         targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    ......
}
```

And don't forget click the link under this log to upgrade your gradle version

Comment: Not "to much", "too much ". Sorry about this spell

Comment: No luck. I tried this till not working